# Difficulty finding type of nested indexes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object, typeerror

I am having trouble assigning a type to this `numsToLtrsMap[usr_query[idx]]`. The numsToLtrsMap is an object of keys that are strings and the values that are strings. I am new to Typescript and have found no solution for it

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYDcCmAnKAVEAZKKDCIAtgEYgQwC8MAFAK4QoD6AjragJ4BcM0KAlmADmASkoA+GAG8AsACgYCxfGgwUSCLQA2UbrwGCA2gF1KMYwG45cxUvAqwtQhEw4UEALIBDAA6UZ8m0UAIgAmIO4gz2JgIIAaa0CFIIBmcJgggBMkADM4hMSggBY0oMEACz48gIKAVhKAKwBrTSrEpIA2EsIwEFa2oIB2Eu9mNz6CgA4SqFoEccCggE4SgHcAD3YAL3mbAF9LWXzFAHpjtWBaNz5kGGywI4VlWAhgTzBTaguUFABlXF1cPpYjA+Bk1twHCRUKIKBJ-G0YKc+NkQWCQeQBDBNJ4VBk+II+FAHopkTRQWsYBJ6ExWBwAHSaJBCKBlGAAWhgAEZRPCEYjjiskDBvPRWXohDAoCBVOotLBPN9POxiTY1BptHSRRAyp9Lr9cMIDnyZTMUGAjW1dlZqoFeQjjgAqJCeYCsxlQKCoGCeGDU4Vq8gE5DkNQoqWSspCxpIdgwEBhyMwBCeTRsOMo6ksNgoWPEHFIDJx94soXkpMptPx30MLMcB3HFUwK02mxPLFID2ochUSHObC4Dw+AyZ2k5gzkoxGA6N7IgFA0NvaedV92etw8xsKU7wV6esCeT0wMBIFZY3CS6XiwTAkvvQggG7h49rWDkzc8V5gXXfP7zgDUZ4oMCZYAdyFqJM2EHTi2-JwCmmi3O80AKlA+gwCshKsm8MBIIQ3hQLGV7erA2R8G4r5gsSLxvNQQRxDAAAMhrEmoprvGqcrgU25hAA)

```
const convertToLtrCombos = (usr_query: string) => {
      const result: string[] = [];

      const numsToLtrsMap ={
        "2": "abc",
        "3": "def",
        "4": "ghi",
        "5": "jkl",
        "6": "mno",
        "7": "pqrs",
        "8": "tuv",
        "9": "wxyz",
        };

      //recursive fn
      const scan = (currStr: string, idx: number) => {
        //if idx is in last digit
        if (idx > usr_query.length - 1) {
          //we push string to result array
          result.push(currStr);
          return;
        }

        {
          /*each letter a usr press gives ref to the key of the value of usr_query based on the idx value of usr_query*/
        }
        const letters = numsToLtrsMap[usr_query[idx]];

        for (const ltr of letters) {
          //concatenate new ltr to string, then move to next idx
          scan(currStr + ltr, idx + 1);
        }
      };

      // call fn starting with an empty string at first idx
      scan("", 0);
      return result;
    };
```

I have tried to assign usr_query as a string and change the numsToLtrsMap as an array of objects. That clear one error but inside the nested indexes gives me an error.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mq56km) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Thanks! I have edited my question. Good looking out!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBk7bm) meet your needs? Note that `usr_query` might contain characters not expected by your code, so you need to harden against the possibility that `letters` might be `undefined` if you want TS to stop complaining.  Let me know if that works for you and I can maybe write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I have a Numpad component that will limit what characters the user inputs. This is perfect.